# Hibernate duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to insert in data base using hibernate in different processes, I get this exception

```
Duplicate entry '58576' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

My Generation strategy was `Generator.Table`.
I changed it to `Generator.identity`, but get the exception

```
field dbid doesn't have default value
```

How can I solve this problem?

my Entity:

```
@Id
    @TableGenerator(name="dbidn",table="dbidpktn",pkColumnName="dbkeyn",
pkColumnValue="dbvaluen",allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "dbidn")
    private Long dbid;
```

Comment: Can you post your entities and dao code?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use DB dependent IDs try

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

And set the primary key field filling on DB level

Answer (score 1):

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "announcement", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "announcement")
private Integer announcementId;
```

use GenericGenerator